Accessing a property in another property within the same interface for type inference
I've been putting in a lot of effort recently to find a way to access one property, say propA, of a type or interface into another property of the same type or interface, say propB, so that I can make a type inference that is dependent on the value of propA.
Notice that discriminated unions wouldn't work here, because the type of propA is actually Record<string, any>, i.e., its keys are dynamic and not pre-defined. Unless there is something I'm missing.
Here is an example of what I had in mind:
type MyType = {
    propA: Record<string, any>;
    propB: keyof MyType["propA"]
}

const example: MyType = {
    propA: {
        name: "Jay",
        age: 20,
    },
    propB: "name" // must be either "name" or "age"
}

Is it even possible?

Since propA type is Record<string, any>, keyof MyType["propA"] will resolve to string instead of the literal union you're looking for, in this case you can use a generic parameter to make sure that object keys are inferred as union instead of a string, but you'll then have to pass in a generic type, it's exhausting to do this if you have a large piece of code, so you can use a function instead to automatically infer the generic parameter: Playground

Your explanation is very clear. Thank you very much. Now I have a solid grasp over when the Record utility type is a good idea and when it's not.

As an option with possibly better DX you could use a make-type generic function:
function makeExample<T extends {propA: Record<string, any>, propB: keyof T['propA']}>(obj: T): T{
    return obj;
}

const example = makeExample({
    propA: {
        name: "Jay",
        age: 20,
    },
    propB: "name" // must be either "name" or "age"
});


Thank you very much for your answer. I actually needed to infer the type in a function, so it turns out your solution was perfect for my use case.
